# Take K apples such that no two are consecutive

Tags: combinatorics

N apples were placed in a row. we have to take K apples. But we can not take two consecutive apples. How many ways are their to take such K apples ?

Like If N=5 and K=2 then answer is 6 as their are 6 such ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine that the apples you don't choose are green and the apples you chose are red, and that we are doing this in reverse - you are inserting your red apples into a line of green apples such that the red apples are not adjacent. Now there are $(N-K)$ green apples and $(N-K+1)$ positions you can put a red apple. So you have to choose $K$ of those $(N-K+1)$ places , and the answer is $${N-K+1 \choose K}$$
For your example, $N=5, K=2$ and there are ${5-2+1 \choose 2} = {4 \choose 2} = 6$ ways, as you said.